# Python shapely polygon line intersection

Tags: python, intersection, shapely

I'm currently working on a small script that calculates the reflection of a ray at a wall of a building in 2D. Therefor I'm using the shapely.geometry.intersection methods which is doing it's job really well. To calculate the reflection ray i need the exact LineString of the certain wall to calculate the normal of it.

Currently I'm splitting the polygon into each of its exterior LineStrings and looking for a intersection.

Is there any other way to get the intersected boundary without splitting the polygon?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why are you splitting the polygon border into separate segments? Can't you just calculate the intersection with the `polygon.exterior` ring?

Comment: Of course I can calculate the intersection with the linearring given by the polygon.exterior feature, but it just returns the intersection points. I need the the the segment that is beeing intersected by the line to calculate the reflection

Comment: there is [`segments_intersections` function](https://bentley-ottmann.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#bentley_ottmann.planar.segments_intersections) in `bentley-ottmann` package which returns dictionary of {intersection point: [pair of intersecting segments indices]} that you may probably use (it is in pure Python with `O(n log n)` time & `O(n)` memory complexity)